# Access to KML tree

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I have some rutes in KML format and I can't modify them. I want to draw them on a map but I also want to get the fist and last points to check for near cities and interesting places.

The problem that Google Maps API does server-side procesing and I cannot access individual elements form it. I searched and tried to use a parser like GeoXML but it's not exactly what I want because it uses its own map style an so on and I have to use Google API maps. I only do need to acces certain elements of KML tree and i will draw them using Google Maps API.

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance for answer in these vacation days(for some).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard KmlLayer in Google Maps for rendering, and then use a 3rd party library like GeoXML (or your own code to read the XML) to grab whatever data you need from the KML and run additional functions based on that.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. Render the main path withthe standard and then analyze the KML and place markers on first and last point. I have elevation info too so I will do calculations about slope(it's walking rute in the mountains).
Can I ask for a hint on how do that? Since the GeoXML documentation is not very good maybe is it better to parse it myself as a regular XML.